# How to use functions like ABS(Absolute function) in DataColumns.Expression?

Tags: regex, datatable, datacolumn

I've many complex functions in excel that I need to represent in Datatable.
Depending on the values of Col1,Col2,Col3 and Col4 I am generating Col5 and Col6 in the Datatable.
For simple stuffs like representing Col5 = Col1 + Col2 is easy.

```
DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn();
totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
totalColumn.ColumnName = "col5";
totalColumn.Expression = "col1 + col2";
dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn);
```

But I've some complex functions like ABS (absolute function). Aggregate function like SUM() takes only 1 argument. SUM(Col1,Col2) function cannot be used as a substitute to Col1 + Col2.
Hence there are some limitations. So is there a way wherein I write regular expressions (REGEX) which is independently and apply it later.

Comment: What is this? Excel? SQL?

Comment: There is data which is represented in excel and I am representing it in a grid in ASP.NET MVC. In my web app data is coming from database.

Comment: Ok. Which database engine? MySQL? Postgres? SQL server?

Comment: SQL Server. Does it matter?